# install4j: Run old launcher (exe file) with OpenJDK

Tags: install4j

We need old installj4 launcher (exe file) created in 2011 to be able to run with Azul Zulu JDK. ij4_nlog says it can't:

```
Searching for a JVM
Has preferred location E:\app\jre_1940.0.18
checkJavaExe (e:\app\jre_1940.0.18\bin\java.exe, [out], 1.5, , 1)
file exists
Exit Code 0
couldn't get version
checkJavaExe returning 0
```

Please see `E:\app\jre_1940.0.18\bin\java.exe -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.31.0.1-win32) (build 1.8.0_181-b02)
OpenJDK Client VM (Zulu 8.31.0.1-win32) (build 25.181-b02, mixed mode)
```

How does it try to get version?

Comment: There is no workaround, you have to upgrade to install4j 7.

Comment: We've accidentally found that our installer from late 2011 was able to run with OpenJDK. Could you please clarify what does it mean 'support of OpenJDK by install4j'?

Comment: The launcher has to be able to parse the version string